# What can cause my TPL tasks to stop running?

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have the following code:

```
while (true)
{
    Task.Run(() =>{
        var request = WebRequest.Create("url1");
        request.GetResponse();
    });

    Task.Run(() =>{
        var request = WebRequest.Create("url2");
        request.GetResponse();
    });

    Thread.Sleep(15000);
}
```

The idea is every 15 seconds invoke a couple of endpoints. It works fine for around 20 mins then eventually the code in the tasks never run. No errors. Have I created too many tasks? There are no out of memory issues either.

Comment: If it is your actual code it is missing `using` (or `Dispose`) - so relatively soon it should be failing the way you see... otherwise please make sure to provide sample that reproduces the problem

Comment: No this is pretty much the code. Thanks for comment but using and disposing what exactly?

Comment: Dispose whatever is disposable (request, response,streams...)

Comment: I see. You mean get a reference to the request object and close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prompted from the comments given by @AlexeiLevenkov getting a reference to the response object from the request.GetResponse, then subsequently closing the response fixed the issue.